# Where do the Night King and his army get the tools and weapons from?

Tags: game-of-thrones

**Where do the Night King and his army of the dead get their swords from?**

Also, in the recent episode S07E06, the army is seen dragging the dragon from the water using heavy chains. **Where did they get such heavy tools from in the ice lands?**

Comment: There is a recent post about the [chains](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/79148/how-did-the-wights-get-the-chain-for-doing-this). About the weapons, probably from the defeated warriors owners of the weapons whom they are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The Night King and the White Walkers are able to make their swords from ice using some form of magic unknown to us at this time.
2. The wights are inheriting the weapons from the people who were once alive and carried them.
3. The chains are unknown at this time...

Comment: Sunken ships.  The wights clearly aren't killed by going under water. Seems like it would be a relatively simple thing to send them under, find some wrecks, bring back the anchor chains.