# Why didn't the Night King resurrect Viserion under water?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In Game of Thrones, we can see in the episode "The Long Night" that the dead can be resurrected from the underground crypts.

Why didn't the Night King resurrect Viserion under water? Why did he have to make so much effort with poor wights with huge chains to extract the dragon from the deep?

Discussion about whether Viserion is a wight or White Walker is available in [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/79207/is-this-thing-a-wight-or-a-white-walker).

Comment: Where the chains came from and how they were able to attach them is still a mystery too IMHO

Comment: I don't think there is an adequate in-universe explanation. The show runners probably decided that they wanted to show Viserion opening his(?) eye revealing that it is blue in a close-up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this thing a wight or a White Walker?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/79207/is-this-thing-a-wight-or-a-white-walker)

Comment: Actually the chains are explained - https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/79148/how-did-the-wights-get-the-chain-for-doing-this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**He changed the dragon into a White Walker, not a Wight**

It is evident from [this answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/79288/33025) that Viserion is a White Walker dragon. We have previously seen the Night King turn Craster's sons into White Walker. It required physical contact.

> we can see in the episode "The Long Night" that the dead can be
>   resurrected from the underground crypts

Those people turned into wights, not White Walkers.

> Why didn't Night King resurrect Viserion under water?

Since physical contact is required and he could not swim it was not possible.

Comment: Viserion was a wight, not a white walker, otherwise, he would have shattered like the other white walkers, instead of crumbling and collapsing like the wights.

Comment: @ChrisDafnis The answer I linked to provides evidence from Season 7 that he is a White Walker dragon (the official script, the eye colour, the physical touch). S7 and the point you suggest in S8 are in contradiction with one another. Considering the writing in Season 8, I will base my answer in Season 7.

Comment: S7 and S8 are written by the same people.
White Walkers are made from living human babies, not dead things.
The eye looked different but was it not just a blue version of a dragon's eye?
White Walkers shatter into ice when killed, wights just de-animate and collapse. Viserion collapsed, he didn't shatter.
I know what it said in the script, but this contradicts everything that has gone before and after it in the show, so I'd say that was the anomaly, not the manner of Viserion's death.

Comment: @ChrisDafnis "S7 and S8 are written by the same people." Yeah, but the writing is not on the same level. Many agree with this. Your entire point is based on a single event that goes against three other details. I think they way Viserion collapses is an anomaly. I have read your answer there too. I'm sorry but this is my final opinion. If you disagree, feel free to write an alternate answer.

Comment: fair enough, we're all entitled to our opinions.
My point is based on a couple of established parts of GoT lore though:
1. White Walkers are created from living beings, wights from the dead. Viserion was clearly dead. I feel that this is the most important part of this plot-point, and making Viserion a 'White Dragon' contradicts everything we have seen about the Night King in the rest of the show.
2. White Walkers shatter, wights de-animate. Viserion de-animated.
Lazy writing, maybe, but where? In Viserion's death(s), or in the season 7 finale?

Comment: @ChrisDafnis We will know when the books come out. Maybe?

Comment: "If" they come out!

Answer (score -3):

Because simple physics. Wights don't do well in waters, reasons for that is, they're dead meat and bones, and do not have much inside of their organs to have them float in water. In living human beings we have enough air inside of lungs to keep as atop water bodies, but when we die it is not the same. Also, he had to touch the Dragon to make it undead, so something makes me think that Dragons are not as easy as human beings to resurrect, so it had to be a direct touch.

Comment: how about resurrecting giants without touching!!!

Comment: Giants are big, larger than humans but a lot smaller than dragons.